# insert quotes for each field using awk

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I am looking for below input based on the sample provided below

**Sample :**

```
eno~ename~address~zip
123~abc~~560000~"a~b~c"
245~"abc ~ def"~hyd~560102
333~"ghi~jkl"~pub~560103
```

**Expected output :**

```
"eno"~"ename"~"address"~"zip"
"123"~"abc"~""~"560000"~"a~b~c"
"245"~"abc ~ def"~"hyd"~"560102"
"333"~"ghi~jkl"~"pub"~"560103"
```

command which i tried in awk it doesn't work if the delimiter value contains in data. If there are any alternate suggestions with perl/sed/awk suggest.

Below is the command : awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i="\""$i"\""}1' FS="~" OFS="~" sample

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk). The only difference is the field separator

Comment: This is not really a duplicate but closely related.

Comment: If you have a different input, make a new question.  Make sure you google before post as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use `FPAT` with `gnu awk`

```
awk -v FPAT='([^~]*)|("[^"]+")' -v OFS="~" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!~/^\"/) $i="\""$i"\""} 1' file
"eno"~"ename"~"address"~"zip"
"123"~"abc"~""~"560000"
"245"~"abc ~ def"~"hyd"~"560102"
"333"~"ghi~jkl"~"pub"~"560103"
```

Instead of telling how the Field Separator looks like, we tell how the filed looks like.  Then test if field not has double quote, if no, add it.

You can then easy change the Field Separator if you like:

```
awk -v FPAT='([^~]*)|("[^"]+")' -v OFS="," '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!~/^\"/) $i="\""$i"\""} 1' file
"eno","ename","address","zip"
"123","abc","","560000"
"245","abc ~ def","hyd","560102"
"333","ghi~jkl","pub","560103"
```

Comment: It is not working as expected for the last two lines.

Comment: @user1485267 You example did not show that.  I rarely see that  that occur, but if you have, you need a new post with a new question for a new solution.

Comment: @user1485267, I totally agree with Jotne here, please always post correct samples which are near to your actual data, when you keep changing your samples it will be hard for all of us to help you too.

Comment: Sorry for changing inputs.. I agree with your point. I will add in new post. Thanks for your solutions Jotne & Ravindre

Comment: You don't need to create a new post, [the one your question was closed as a dup of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001) shows you how to solve your problem whether your input contains newlines or not. Just do what it shows there to separate the input into fields and then `gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$i); $i="\""$i"\""` in a loop to wrap every field in double quotes before printing the record.

Comment: I didnt understood where should i add that statement i am new to awk exploring based on the scenarios..

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(tested with provided samples only).

```
awk 'BEGIN{s1="\"";FS=OFS="~"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i!~/^\"|\"$/){$i=s1 $i s1}}} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
"eno"~"ename"~"address"~"zip"
"123"~"abc"~""~"560000"
"245"~"abc ~ def"~"hyd"~"560102"
"333"~"ghi~jkl"~"pub"~"560103"
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                      ##Starting BEGIN section of awk program here.
  s1="\""                   ##Setting variable s1 to " here.
  FS=OFS="~"                ##Setting value of FS and OFS as ~ here.
}                           ##Closing BEGIN block of awk code here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){       ##Starting for loop here from i=1 to till value of NF here.
    if($i!~/^\"|\"$/){      ##Checking condition of value of current field is NOT having s1 value in it.
      $i=s1 $i s1           ##Adding s1 variable before and after the value of $i.
    }                       ##Closing block for if condition.
  }                         ##Closing block for for loop here.
}                           ##Closing main block here.
1                           ##Mentioning 1 will print the lines of Input_file.
'  Input_file               ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

Comment: What if there is a field like `"a~b~c"`?

Comment: @oguzismail, ok didn't consider it since it was NOT in OP's samples, let me fix it now.

Comment: I wouldn't fix it, this is clearly a duplicate. See my comment on the question. Upvoted since the logic is clever though

Comment: `123~abc~~560000"a~b~c"` this should not be a valid input, since you only use double quote around field, not not within field, and since `~` is used as FS, `560000"a~b~c"` this part will break all. Correct should be `560000~"a~b~c"`

Comment: It think its better to test if field not starts with double quote `if($i!~/^\"/)`, not contains double quote. `if($i !~ s1)`

Comment: @Jotne, sure, added it now, thanks for letting know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : It didn't work exactly for second and third line. It gave invalid result

Comment: @user1485267, please check now, edited the solution.

Comment: Should i consider the first message or explanation message to test it.

Comment: @Jotne, we should actually add condition for checking lines ending with `"` too, which I added that condition  now.

Comment: @user1485267, refresh my answer. Yes please anyone you could try it out, I have edited both of them.

Comment: Thanks Ravinder, It works as expected. I have two questions based on the above solution. 1) If my OFS value is different. It replace all FS values with OFS value. But it should not happen for the data. 2) If encoding characters like japanese/chinese values comes in data it should not create a problem.

Comment: It doesn't work if we have a new line character in data which is in quotes

Comment: @user1485267, for `OFS` output field separator you could set it in `BEGIN` section. For other language characters I haven't tested it you could test it once.

Comment: @user1485267, You haven't mentioned new line samples, so this code is not written as per it.

Comment: For OFS i have modified your code in below way, It doesn't work. awk 'BEGIN{s1="\"";FS="~";OFS="~"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i!~/^\"|\"$/){$i=s1 $i s1}}} 1' Input_file

Comment: @user1485267, in my code it is already `FS=OFS="~"` not sure which modification you had done to it?

Comment: Sorry, copy paste issue.. I am trying to rewrite sample output to comma delimiter awk 'BEGIN{s1="\"";FS="~";OFS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i!~/^\"|\"$/){$i=s1 $i s1}}} 1' Input_file

Comment: I have added my input for new line data..

Comment: @ravinder : Can i know about this  if($i!~/^\"|\"$/) what it does.. the tilda which is present in if condition is it delimiter value ? If yes, in case if my delimiter value is semi-colon it fails